# Error While trying to add custom rule for Apex PMD

Tags: apex, pmd

I'm trying to add some custom rule for my apex classes in PMD. But while trying to run designer command to PMD to create the Xpath for the rule, I'm getting below error:

**You seem to be missing the JavaFX runtime.
Please install JavaFX on your system and try again.
See https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/**

I have already downloaded the latest javaFX file and set the JAVAFX_HOME environment variable as well as mentioned in the PMD document. Am I missing anything else?

Environment variables in my bash_profile file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export JAVAFX_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-18.0.1/lib
export PATH_TO_FX=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-18.0.1/lib
```

Comment: You need v8 or v11. Ironically, installing the latest version may not work.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox, installing v8 actually solved the issue. it's pretty strange to be honest is that with latest java version pmd designer doesn't work.

Comment: hello @sfdcfox I'm trying to create a Xpath for my Apex class where a SOQL query shouldn't be assigned to a Sobject. This is my Xpath "/UserClass/Method/BlockStatement/VariableDeclarationStatements/VariableDeclaration/SoqlExpression" but it's not working. Do you have any suggestions on this ? This is my first try with Xpath actually.

Comment: I run into this every few month and never find a solution. The above comments did not help. Here is what I tried https://github.com/pmd/pmd/discussions/4153